# Magento 2.2: assign bundle product to configurable product

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, magento2.2, bundled-product

I tried to assign bundle products to the configurable product, but I cannot assign bundle product.

In configurable product, I can see the bundle product, but when I clicked on save button Magento automatically remove the bundle Product.

**1. Product selection in configurable product**

[image]

**2. After Product selection in configurable product**

[image]

**3. After configurable product save**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer this link.I have faced same issue and this is the default  functionality which is given by magento.Please check below link.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8828

Answer (score 0):

By default there is no way to assign bundle products to configurable.

You can use below 3rd Party extension to make it work.

Hope it will help you.

[Configurable Bundle](https://www.wizkunde.nl/magento-2-configurable-bundle.html)

Comment: In bundle product, we can manage the inventory of simple product which is associated with the product, but can it be possible to manage with this extension because I do not think this extension will reduce the simple product Qty. @Lazy Coder

Answer (score 0):

By default you can assign Bundle products to Configurable.

But if Bundle product has required options it won't be seen, and this is logicaly correct.
Interesting that relations with this kind of products will be in database.

But if you want in any way to show all child product, please follow next steps.
Have a look at getUsedProducts() and used function getConfiguredUsedProductCollection()
where there is a  method which is filtering required options - ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
This is public method so you can make a plugin on it and exclude this filtering.

Plugin on Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection

```
public function aroundAddFilterByRequiredOptions(Collection $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        if ($subject->getEntity()->getTypeId() != 4) {
            return $proceed($subject);
        }

        return $subject;
    }
```